# Change fancybox close button title/tooltip

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a way to translate the tooltips in fancybox, e.g. the tooltip on the close button?

I have done this in the afterShow callback to change the value to Danish and seems to work.. or is there a better way to change it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.mapoverlay").fancybox({
          width : '90%',
          height : '90%',
          fixed: false,
          autoSize : false,
          autoCenter : true,
          afterLoad  :  function() {
        loadMap();
          },
          afterShow  :  function() {
        $("a.fancybox-close").attr("title", "Luk");
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

**Edit:**
This code seems to work fine.

I got a syntax error when writing this.. I think you missed something?
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

I saw this post here: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/7

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.mapoverlay").fancybox({
          width : '90%',
          height : '90%',
          fixed: false,
          autoSize : false,
          autoCenter : true,
          afterLoad  :  function() {
        loadMap();
          },
          tpl: { 
        closeBtn: '<div title="Test" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"></div>' 
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `.tpl` option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.mapoverlay").fancybox({
    width : '90%',
    height : '90%',
    fixed: false,
    autoSize : false,
    autoCenter : true,
    afterLoad :  function() {
      loadMap();
    },
    tpl: {
        '<a title="Your title here!" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>'
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT** : the correct format for the `tpl` option is

```
tpl : {
 closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### For a permanent change:

Just replace "Close" in *fancybox/source/* `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` ( and/or `jquery.fancybox.js`).

Look for `closeBtn` and then change its `a` `title`

[image]

---

### For a temporary title change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     tpl : {
        closeBtn : '<a title="CUSTOM TITLE HERE" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>'
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but editing source code is bad practice as you might lose all your changes if you update the plugin, and if it's a big update your changes might not be compatible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.fancybox.close()` option:

example: 
`<a onclick="$.fancybox.close();" href="javascript:;">Your text </a>`